# Encoding discrepancy with Iris Dataset

Tags: python, encoding, iris-dataset

After I downloaded the dataset as iris.data, I renamed it to iris.data.txt. I was trying to circumvent this reported error on SO:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 8: invalid continuation byte
```

After reading up, I tried this:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('iris.data.txt', header=None, names=names,encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

This partly solved the error but some rows were still garbage.

Then I tried to open it with Sublime, save it with utf-8 encoding and then `dataset = pd.read_csv('iris.data.txt', header=None, names=names,encoding="utf-8")`

But this doesn't solve the problem either. I'm running Python 3 on Mac OS. What could possibly render the data readable directly?

[EDIT]: 
The datatype reads: Web archive. In Spyder, the file appears as iris.data.webarchive

If I try `dataset = pd.read_csv('iris.data.webarchive', header=None)`, it gives this traceback:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 5
```

If I try `dataset = pd.read_csv('iris.data', header=None)`, it gives `FileNotFoundError: File b'iris.data' does not exist`

Comment: strange simple pd.read_csv('iris.data', header=None) works for me...

Comment: How is the data seperated.? Try giving the `sep` argument to `read_csv`

Comment: @SarthakNegi: Please see edit above.

Comment: @SreeramTP: It's a popular dataset. I'm not sure if we need the sep here

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my rookie mistake. I had to save the page as 'source' instead of 'webarchive' (which is the default Mac setting)